Supplying a reference to a bad former employee
Towards the start of this year, we had to fire someone I was managing due to (among other things) poor performance. We/I offered to supply a reference for ongoing employment. Their new company (I understand they've signed a contract already, for a somewhat related role) has now reached out for one, and addition to the usual questions about confirming employment dates they also have a bunch of questions about rating candidate performance, would I hire them again, etc. I gather from the form that these are standard questions for their process but I don’t think either me or the former employee were expecting it.
Constraints:

I don’t want to lie

I don't want to be mean to the former employee, while I don't think they were very good I have no animosity towards them

I don't think I can easily dodge this since last week they reached out to confirm that I was still OK to do this (obviously this was before I saw the form the new employer would send)

It's hard to write something generic because the employer's form is not free text but rather has specific questions as outlined above

I obviously don't want to do anything that could get my company (or me, I guess) into legal trouble - this is UK if that's relevant.


I have already asked my manager for advice and also written to our HR, plus asked friends/family who are not involved in the situation. I've yet to hear back from HR but a common suggestion has been to write to the former employee and confirm:

What they said about their departure from our company to the new employer, so as not to cause any problems.

Given the above constraints, whether they still want me to provide a reference (although if I don't I'm not sure what the new employer would make of it).


What would be the best course of action here?

The closest post I could find is https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35657/asked-to-give-what-would-be-a-negative-reference?rq=1
However I think this is a different situation as there the former employer (ie me) had not already agreed to give a reference (and the advice was to not agree with this), whereas here it's already been said

Do you not think it's a bit late to refuse?

The government website doesn't have a whole lot to say on the subject:  https://www.gov.uk/work-reference, also some stuff on the acas site:  https://www.acas.org.uk/providing-a-job-reference/what-employers-can-say-in-a-reference

It is not unlawful to provide a negative but entirely truthful reference https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunal-decisions/mrs-n-leeks-v-norfolk-and-norwich-university-hospitals-nhs-foundation-trust-3303975-2018

Please outline the extent of the employee's inadequacy. If he/she were inadequate across-the-board, i.e. in all major aspects of the job they did, how did it happen that they were selected in the first go down ? Did you have a role in this person's pre-appointment assessment and selection ? If the selection process was inadequate to assess the true level of core skills in this persons's case, shouldn't the company also share the blame for hiring this employee ? We can't really be fair all around if we aren't fully honest about the whole process up to now.

I don't want to go into too much detail in case anything becomes identifiable, but essentially they were technically incapable (talked well but didn't actually get stuff done), and additionally had some attitude problems that were brought to me independently by several people on their project.
I did not personally interview them before hiring but their interviews went well, I suspect because it's hard to identify the issues they had in the limited time frame of an interview (though partly as a result of this we have modified our interview process slightly).

@Moo Would you please post that as an answer? I'll gladly upvote it. It's weird that all the answers here suggest lying (at least by omission) while the obvious answer of "tell the truth" is missing. But I don't know anything about the UK so I don't feel like answering myself.

@WilliamSmith your caution about identifiability is warranted, and indeed you have already posted enough specific information (such as the date when employee was let go, date when they contacted you, surprise questions, location is UK) that you really cannot rule out that there is only one such manager-employee pair which satisfies the constraints of this post. If you haven't already, I would change some of the specifics.

There is the cop-out answer which is for all these questions write the following:
"Our company policy for references is to only confirm employment start and end dates and position"
(or some variation on that theme)
Standard form meet generic answer.

That is clearly the way to go. The only downside: If this is NOT company policy, it's still a lie.

You don't even need to state it is company policy, just give the minimal details and leave them to assume that you're doing it as company policy.

I have always assumed that it was illegal to even ask, although I can't give specific reasons for that. What is certain to my mind is that giving anything other than what you suggest, can potentially leave the company open to litigation - from the new employer, if you give a good reference, that they feel is not accurate, and from the employee, if they feel you have given them an unfair evaluation.

Which company's policy?  It could be the company policy of William Smith Inc (the OP) to do exactly that.  The problem came up when he offered and confirmed to write this employee a reference letter.

I am still waiting for HR to properly confirm my enquiry but it seems to be pointing this way from them so I think this is probably the answer

Also just to clarify, it's not my company, I'm a team lead. In the firing meeting the offer to provide a reference was made by HR (though I agreed, both then and subsequently as I felt it was the right thing to do).

@Hilmar It may still be a lie, but it's kind of the whitest of lies. OP should be willing to stretch that far, otherwise their constraints may turn out to be irreconcilable.

@Hilmar The only other alternative I see is just going complete-radio-silence on the new employer, which is of course also an option. Stop responding to them, you are not under any obligation to follow any of their processes.

@Hilmar - Every Company policy, at one point, was not a company policy ;)

"As a matter of policy we..." doesn't define who "we" are but implies the company even though it really means the OP and some randoms online

@WilliamSmith - if the offer of a reference was made by HR, it definitely sounds like either HR should be providing that reference, or should be providing guidance to you on the content of that reference.

They now have given me a template to use

Can you indicate - without disclosing anything identifying in doing so - the general lines on which they format the reference ? We are indeed, sir, all agog on this delicate matter . . .

Basically as indicated above, generic soft praise without going into any detail.

US resident here...I tend to lean toward the old saying, "If you can't say anything nice, don't say anything at all." You can simply say that your company does not provide details regarding past performance evaluations. As far as whether you would hire him again, I recommend consulting with HR. Ask the question, "If this former employee applied for a job different to the one he had, but was qualified for, would he be eligible to be hired if chosen by the hiring manager?"
You're not saying anything that would jeopardize his position due to your responses, while protecting yourself and your organization by avoiding details. They've already hired him; let them do their own discovery. Maybe he will be a stellar employee, maybe he won't. What he won't be able to claim is not getting the chance to succeed or fail because of something his past employer said.
As a sidebar, the fact the hiring company is doing this type of investigation after hiring him speaks volumes about them. If they have trust issues, maybe they should do more homework on their applicants before offering them a position.

Referring to you last paragraph. It's fairly standard (at least in the UK) to hire someone "subject to references" so I don't think there's anything suspicious about what's going on.

A big part of why being that candidates are usually reticent to provide references from their current employer before they have an offer letter, because of the risks of retaliation by the current employer if they don't get the job. So the standard is 'offer subject to references' and then ask there current employer for references, prior to them starting work. So they have a signed contract, but not completed hiring.

@user1937198 I'm curious: say I get this signed contract / incomplete hiring, I ask my current employer for references, then the new company meets a better candidate and rejects me "based on the references" (so they say, and it's hard to argue with that). My current employer has found out I'm looking around, and the new company won't hire me any more. What kind of guarantee does the signed contract provide me?

@Simone Legally? That's a constructive dismissal, and they would be required by a pay you redundancy pay as specified by the contract. Because its not 'better references' its 'unsatisfactory references' which they would then need to present to an employment tribunal to argue that they weren't satisfactory. It doesn't benefit the company to do that, because its basically equivalent to making someone redundant on there first day, which is a risk you have any time you switch jobs.

@Simone Practically? Its not so much about that scenario, as the companies admitting that references are really these days about confirming that you aren't lying on your CV and not much else, because of how many companies just have blanket policies of not saying anything other than employment dates. And theres no point demanding that from the current employer of a candidate, before you are sure you want to hire them, including things like salary negotiation. And the offer letter is a convinent point in the process to mark that.

@user1937198 Then I fail to see the practical advantage. The "subject to references" offer seems to be an actual contract (if violated, it's like I'm being fired): if you're that far into the hiring process, why bother to find out whether I lied on the CV? "Ok, we've talked to you, we like you, we want to hire you for this much money and these benefits, sign here to start on Monday - oh wait, you mentioned you worked there for 5 years but it's 4, we don't want you any more and we will fire you for that" Am I getting it wrong? Sorry for the question, I'm not from UK, just genuinely curious.

@Simone I think you're on the right track, but the 5 vs 4 years is probably not what will make the difference. But if you claim you worked as a software engineer for 5 years and get a job based on that, and then by following up on the reference the new company finds out that you actually worked as a telephone support agent that might change their mind... So the contract is more of a "you got the job unless you deliberately lied or misrepresented your past".

Pretty much what fgysin said, or the cases of, claimed to have worked at big major company, and then you follow up on the reference, and find out the person never worked there.

Of course I was being exaggerate and I was expecting a rejection to be for more serious reasons. But then again, this sounds like I can blatantly lie on the CV, apply for a position well above my skills and experience, get me hired by interviewing well, and then when they find out and "fire/not-fire" me I get redundancy pay - so this exposes the company to the risk of giving a potential liar a guarantee...

In the UK it is the normal practice to be offered a job "subject to satisfactory references". You accept the job offer by providing your reference contact details.  This is sufficient to create a contract under UK law. (offer, acceptance, consideration).

@simone - in the UK, most employers would include a probation period in the employment contract.  Typically the probation period has a notice period of a week.  If your new employer wants to get rid of you quickly, they will simply pay you your 1 week notice period and terminate your contract.   Making someone redundant in the UK creates ongoing constraints on the employer - not being able to recruit someone into a similar job role for 12 months.


I've yet to hear back from HR but a common suggestion has been to write to the former employee and confirm:
[...]
What would be the best course of action here?

To wait for your HR's response and indications on how to proceed or handle this, so you are sure you are acting in a correct and legal way (or rather, you are not saying something that could put you in trouble).
Regarding writing to the former employee again and ask if they still want you as reference, it would seem that at this point (the new company already reached out to you) this is not possible anymore without raising some eyebrows and without you looking bad by taking back your offer to serve as reference on the last moment.
Another option is to just answer the questions you feel ok and capable to answer, as well as those that don't put you (and your company) on a tricky situation, like disclosing internal and probably confidential things like performance rating and other things.
In hindsight, it sounds that you offered to serve as reference out of courtesy, and not much because this is a person you would really recommend. In any case, keep your comments objective, professional and as neutral as possible.

Many companies only provide a minimum of information when giving a reference.  They do this to protect themselves from the predicament that you are in.
You promised that you would go beyond the basic dates of employment, but were then shocked to discover that any questions beyond dates of employment would expect you to give an opinion.

I gather from the form that these are standard questions for their
process but I don’t think either me or the former employee were
expecting it.

The questions you were asked are not any different than ones you would be asked if the hiring company called you. These are the norm, if the hiring company can as the questions.
Even if you were writing a letter without prompts, the hiring company would be looking for these types of statements.
You need HR to tell you how to proceed.

"You promised that you would go beyond the basic dates of employment" - Did OP actually say anything like this?

No we never promised anything aside from a "standard reference".

The former employee believed you promised more than dates of employment. Providing dates isn't a reference, that just confirms that they worked there.

Actually their most recent message to me confirming that I was still OK to provide the reference (last week) confirmed that they were assuming the reference would only consist of dates of employment. Obviously they weren't to know so I don't blame them for it, but had the question at the time been whether I was willing to make a fulsome recommendation, I would have had a rather more guarded answer.

I have been in a similar situation, in the UK - but about 15 years ago.
About 6 months after an employee was dismissed, I was contacted for a reference by an employer that had offered him a new role, subject to satisfactory references.
The company guidance I was given by my employer, was that if the reference was in writing, I had to stick to start date, end date, and a general summary of responsibilities and whether performance expectations were met, or not.
However, references by telephone I was given the freedom to have a more open conversation, as long as I followed the basic rules about being honest, accurate and fair.
In the UK there is a general convention that you do not give a bad reference, but it is also legally important that you do not paint a dishonest overall impression by being selective in details that you share.
This is what I did.
Before agreeing to give a reference, I just said that there was a couple of issues that i need to handle fairly carefully about their reference, and asked if they could give me a short summary about what they had been told about why he ceased working for my team.  From the couple of sentences they said, it was clear he had been open and honest with them, so the first issue that i had to handle carefully was handled by me confirming that how they described it was a fair and full description of the reason why he was dismissed - then I had a really good telephone conversation with his new manager about the challenges of being his manager.
Their main concern that they needed clarity on, was satisfied. I was able to confirm that their assessments of his strengths and weaknesses was in line with what i had experienced, and they seemed to be a better match for him as his employer than we had been. His main challenge was that his English was particularly poor, which meant that we struggled with both communication of work duties and on the job training to broaden his skills. He had solid Web Site development skills but struggled to pick up skills in the application development aspects that was 90% of our workload. The bits of Web Site tech that he did, was done efficiently and to a higher standard than anyone else on my team was able to achieve, even if my other team members were given considerably longer timeframes.
Would I have agreed to complete a questionnaire ranking system on them?  Probably not. I would have said that with this specific person, I am happy to give an honest, accurate and balanced reference, but that form does not allow me to do it.  Would I confirm as true something that the employee is lying or being misleading about? No absolutely not. I would say something along the lines of "I have some additional or different perspectives and recollections of these events"

Get legal advice
There have been successful cases brought over misleading references. This has gone both ways, an employee suing over a misleadingly bad reference or a future employer suing over a misleadingly good reference.

A lawsuit over a reference would be ridiculous and countries with working court systems would just laugh at anyone attempting such. Plus it is going to be very hard to prove that the misleading reference is the sole thing that caused them to get/miss the job - what kind of employer hires someone solely based on a single reference, ignoring interviews, CV etc?

@Lundin "A lawsuit over a reference would be ridiculous" - if your most recent employer is making up egregious lies about you in an environment where asking for references is standard, that could outright ruin your future career prospects. Hardly seems like something that should be laughed out of court. But of course, that isn't what's being asked in this question (even if it's mentioned in the answer). I don't think there's legally much to worry about in providing a reference that's fudges details in favour of the employee (not that I'd really recommend that).

*Has* there been successful lawsuits against references for providing misleading good references? Citation needed on that. I can imagine an employer suing an employee (maybe) for fabricating significant parts of their work history. But I struggle to imagine a reference being a primary factor in such a lawsuit, or a reference being implicated in that (assuming they're well-meaning and it's not e.g. outright fraud of someone saying they employed the person when they didn't, to knowingly allow them to infiltrate the employer for malicious purposes).

@Lundin I have been involved in situations like this from the employer's side and in our jurisdiction too (CH) there are absolutely legal considerations involved and we definitely wouldn't fill out any such form sent to us. The only thing we would give is our kind-of-standardized letter outlining responsibilities, dates, some other information about the job the person had and very little information about performance.

@NotThatGuy citation given. The cause of action is negligent misstatement.

@NotThatGuy In which case there's quite clearly a conflict between the ex employer and the candidate and there will be two sides of that. As the interviewer you might want to at least hear the candidate's side of it. I've been in that position as interviewer,  as mentioned in the answer I posted. And in my case it give me a really bad impression about the company that badmouthed the candidate. I very much doubt they were doing anything illegal by badmouthing them though, but that's a discussion for a different site.

@Nobody Same here and I wouldn't fill in any paper either, that's ridiculous. References are taken over phone or otherwise they are seriously wasting my time. Furthermore when acting as reference you are not necessarily working for that company any longer either. Contacting whoever was the candidate's closest manager is a relevant reference. Contacting some generic HR person at the company... not at all relevant.

Sorry, too expensive.

Since it sounds like you're willing to provide a reference, but not answer the employer's questions, I'd propose something in line with that:
Tell them you're unable to go into too much detail about past employees (or that you're unable to provide answers to about some of those questions) as a matter of policy, and instead give them a standard reference letter where you talk about their strengths and such.
It's possible that this would raise more concerns than simply saying you can't provide a reference at all as a matter of policy. This depends on how in-depth the questionnaire is, and whether there's something that isn't necessarily too concerning, but still is something a past employer may not be comfortable sharing.

Another option is to just ignore their questionnaire entirely and send them a standard reference letter. And if they come back and ask you to complete the questionnaire, simply politely refer back to your reference letter to find all necessary details. This certainly isn't the most agreeable response, but while it's possible that they'd view that as you not wanting to be honest in the questionnaire, one might also expect such a response from someone who's a bit "stuck up" and just doesn't have the patience to jump through other people's hoops. I would guess that it's not super common to ask references to fill in questionnaires, in which case this response would be somewhat less suspicious. That may reflect somewhat poorly on you, rather than reflecting poorly on the employee. You can decide if that's a desirable outcome.
Of course it may somewhat reflect on them in that they chose you as a reference, but this is less so if you were their manager in their recent employment, as that's a fairly standard reference to provide.

You probably shouldn't agree to be a reference if you're unwilling to answer "yes" to "would you hire them again" (whether that's honest or not).
They probably shouldn't ask you to be a reference if you fired them for poor performance. But it's also possible that taking that risk is their best option (not that this is your problem).

In my final year studying engineering in the '80s, we did employment law and industrial relations in final year as most engineers tend to move into management in their 30s. On the question of writing references for ex-employees who have been moved on, our lecturer advised no overt negative evaluations lest an employee come to read the reference and take issue with it. Rather, he suggested we use a sort of phrasing in our references that would allow personnel managers to decode the limitations - professional or character-wise - of the employee.
Personally, I would refine this a bit more as lawyers have long since referred to such phrasing in assorted employment law cases. How I would do it would be to explicitly indicate the strong (or at least adequate) parts of the ex-employee's capabilities while omitting any evaluation of weaker aspects of their work-performance.
So the performance evaluation part of the reference (for say a software developer) might run a bit like:
" . . . After initial training, Mr/Ms X's performance was generally satisfactory during his/her period in our employment, particularly in conceptualizing models for software systems and in system documentation."
This much description of X's performance is - generally though not entirely - true. But of course hiring managers would be able to infer that other vital qualities of a good developer like good coding skills and habits, testing ability, adherence to organization software conventions, team-mate support, communication skill, etc are left uncommented on . . .

Except in this question, the employee's performance was a problem, so saying it was satisfactory would be a lie. The only way to answer this question, without saying the reason the employee was fired, is to indicate that the policy is not to confirm that the employee worked for the company as stated on their resume. I, however, believe that I would instead state whether their performance was satisfactory or not. I am covered by the fact anything I state would have been in their performance reviews.

We haven't yet heard from OP as to the extent of the employee's performance inadequacy. It would be very unlikely that an employee with across-the-board inadequacy would be kept in position past the initial training phase. Not unless the company made a great (and incorrect) assumption regarding the employee's foundation skills - and it was only after initial training that this assumption was shown to be wrong and the employee even then didn't show the capability to acquire such skills to the degree required. I'll leave a question on this to OP.

To address why we kept them as long as we did, there was already some discussion  amongst management concerning whether we would need to extend their probation, but in the end we decided that due to projects being in flux at that time it was not really fair to assume their bad performance was solely an issue with them. I had an informal warning session with them and we monitored progress more closely. At first it seemed like they might be improving a little but sadly it didn't bear out and more issues kept arising, to the point where their continued employment was no longer tenable.

It all sounds like you only had a (perhaps weak?) say in their remaining rather than a significant say in this decision. I feel that your organization has senior management and HR management that  prefers to decide matters but not accept responsibility for such decisions. I would worry about your future progress in that company to be frank as much as the immediate awkward matter of a reference for an under-performing ex-employee.

So, all in all, I would refer the reference to the HR department in this case.

@Trunk - The individual's performance was poor enough to be fired for their performance. It must have been poor enough for the author to list why the employee was fired.

@Donald  But OP didn't go into specifics on where the ex-employee fell down workwise - due to fear of identifying the organization, he says. I just thought there normally would be some saving graces in anyone performance - even where the performance in entirety would be clearly inadequate. (Though naturally we must be mindful of smothering someone's reference with faint praise.) Mind you, OP has mentioned other attitudinal issues too that were communicated to him by others in the ex-employee's work group.  Yet I feel that the selection processes in OP's organization need a fresh rebuild.

When hiring someone yourself, you'll find yourself very grateful to trustworthy references and so when acting as a reference yourself, you are indirectly returning the favour. So "don't lie" is absolutely necessary.
However, it is bad form to speak ill of previous employees even if they didn't do a good job. In a professional ending of someone's employment, no matter who initiated it, there's no hard feelings from either party and thereby also a silent agreement that the previous employee will not speak bad of the company and vice versa.
Keep in mind that everything you say as a reference will reflect back to the company, if you still work there. So starting to bad-mouth previous employers might look worse for your company than for the person getting bad-mouthed.
I recall this happening once when I snooped around for references beyond what the candidate had given me. One company where they had worked at was completely unprofessional, bad-mouthing the candidate and with no concrete arguments at that. To the point where I had to completely discard that reference and even sympathized with the candidate quitting their job there.
Still you can hint of things without bad-mouthing the candidate. Suppose they were really bad at showing up punctually at work in the morning and the interviewer asks you as a reference if the candidate was punctual. Then you can always choose to say "I can't comment on that" or "we have a policy not to disclose that outside the origanization" etc - you don't have to give an answer.
Now if you did answer most other questions, the interviewer will find themselves with a mysterious blank spot, which is a warning sign. Then they can get back to the candidate and ask the question to them directly. How they chose to reply is then up to themselves. But then you as a reference haven't thrown them directly under the bus.
In particular, you should not discuss health issues, family status or other private information you might have. That would be both unethical and possibly also have legal consequences (GDPR and all that).
